# React Ag Grid with material theme classes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ag-grid

Is there any way to implement material theme based classes to Ag Grid rows. Below is the scenario I have. Thanks in Advance

**Material Styles**

```
const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    actionIcon: {
        '& svg': {
            fontSize: theme.palette.currentTheme.gridIconSize,
            color: theme.palette.currentTheme.gridIconColor,
            opacity: 0.6,
        }
      },
      rowNormal: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.currentTheme.gridValueBackgroundColor,
        color: theme.palette.currentTheme.gridValueFontColor,
      },
      rowHeader: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.currentTheme.gridHeaderBackgroundColor,
        color: theme.palette.currentTheme.gridHeaderFontColor,
      }

}));
```

**Row style function**

```
this.state = { 
    getRowStyle: (params) => {
        const {classes}= this.props;
        if (params.node.group) {
            return (classes.rowNormal)
        } else {
            return (classes.rowHeader)
        }
    },
};
```

**AG Grid**

```
<AgGridReact
  modules={this.state.modules}
  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
  defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
  debug={true}
  rowData={this.state.rowData}
  onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
  frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
  getRowStyle={this.state.getRowStyle}
/>
```

Comment: ag-grid already has a theme called `ag-theme-material` [demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php?theme=ag-theme-material)

Comment: I need to change the row background based on the material ui theme selected {theme.palette.primaryColor}

Comment: @Amir Did you ever figure this out? I have a MUI project and debating if AG-Grid is worth the extra effort to have it play nice with MUI theme vs just using the build-in MUI table components

Comment: Same problem, How do I style ag-grid according to my MUI theme?

Comment: @KshitijV97 sorry for very late reply. I posted the solution what works for me. If you have any better solution please suggest that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I created a ag-grid as a separate component and changed the className according to the theme. use the custom ag-grid component (Datagrid) in the required area.

```
class Datagrid extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
            columns,
            data,
            defaultColDef,
            currentTheme,
            ...rest
    } = this.props;

    return (
            <div
                className={currentTheme.isDarkTheme ? 'ag-theme-balham-dark' : 'ag-theme-balham'}
            >
                <AgGridReact
                    reactNext={true}
                    columnDefs={columns}
                    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                    rowData={data}
                    animateRows={true}
                    {...rest}
                >
                    {children}
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        );
  }
}
export default Datagrid;
```